# Why Android DownloadManager throws SecurityException after opening a deleted file?

Tags: java, android

Why I am receiving Security Exception when I try to open a deleted downloaded file via DownloadManager?

Here is my code:

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.StringRes;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.MimeTypeMap;
import android.webkit.URLUtil;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.FileDescriptor;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    public static final int EXTERNAL_STORAGE_RC = 101;

    private ImageView mDownloadedImageIv;
    private Button mDownloadBtn;
    private Button mShowImageBtn;
    private EditText mUrlInputEt;

    private long mDownloadId = -1;
    private DownloadReceiver mDownloadReceiver;
    private DownloadManager mDownloadManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initUi();

        requestPermissions();

        mDownloadBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        mShowImageBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

        mDownloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

        mDownloadReceiver = new DownloadReceiver();
        registerReceiver(mDownloadReceiver, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        unregisterReceiver(mDownloadReceiver);

        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void requestPermissions() {
        if (!isExternalStoragePermissionGranted()) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    EXTERNAL_STORAGE_RC);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == EXTERNAL_STORAGE_RC && grantResults.length == 1 &&
                grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setTitle(R.string.perm_denied_ad_title)
                        .setMessage(R.string.perm_denied_ad_message)
                        .setNegativeButton(R.string.perm_denied_negative_btn_text, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                requestPermissions();
                            }
                        });

                builder.show();
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean isExternalStoragePermissionGranted() {
        return ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) ==
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }

    private void initUi() {
        mDownloadedImageIv = findViewById(R.id.downloaded_image_iv);
        mDownloadBtn = findViewById(R.id.download_btn);
        mShowImageBtn = findViewById(R.id.show_image_btn);
        mUrlInputEt = findViewById(R.id.url_input_et);
    }

    private boolean isValidExtension(String url) {
        String fileExt = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url);

        if (fileExt.matches("jpeg|png|bmp")) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private void startDownloadingFromUrl() {
        if (!isExternalStoragePermissionGranted()) {
            showToast(R.string.permission_is_not_granted_err);
            return;
        }

        String url = mUrlInputEt.getText().toString();

        if (!Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(url).matches()) {
            showToast(R.string.invalid_url_err);
            return;
        }

        if (!isValidExtension(url)) {
            showToast(R.string.invalid_url_extension_err);
            return;
        }

        String filenameToSave = URLUtil.guessFileName(url, null, null);

        DownloadManager.Request downloadRequest = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url))
                .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, filenameToSave);

        mDownloadId = ((DownloadManager)getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE)).enqueue(downloadRequest);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.download_btn:
                startDownloadingFromUrl();
                break;
            case R.id.show_image_btn:
                showDownloadedImage();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    private void showDownloadedImage() {
        if (mDownloadId == -1) {
            return;
        }

        ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFd = null;

        try {
            parcelFd = mDownloadManager.openDownloadedFile(mDownloadId);
            if (parcelFd == null) {
                throw new FileNotFoundException();
            }
            FileDescriptor fd = parcelFd.getFileDescriptor();

            Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fd);

            if (image != null) {
                mDownloadedImageIv.setImageBitmap(image);
            } else {
                showToast(R.string.downloaded_image_does_not_exists_err);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            showToast(R.string.downloaded_image_does_not_exists_err);
        } finally {
            if (parcelFd != null) {
                try {
                    parcelFd.close();
                } catch (IOException ignored) { }
            }
        }
    }

    private void showToast(@StringRes int stringId) {
        Toast.makeText(this, stringId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private class DownloadReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            long id = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1);

            if (mDownloadId == id) {
                mShowImageBtn.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/url_input_et"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/url_et_hint"
        android:inputType="textUri"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/show_image_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:text="@string/show_image_btn_text"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/download_btn"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/download_btn" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/download_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/download_btn_text"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/cardview_image"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/url_input_et" />


    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardview_image"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:cardElevation="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/url_input_et"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/url_input_et"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/download_btn">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/downloaded_image_iv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_image_24" />

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. Enter url that ends with .png, .jpeg or .bmp
2. Press the DOWNLOAD button to download image
3. Delete image via the Android File Explorer
4. Press SHOW IMAGE button

The code fails at this line and I can't handle this exception:

> parcelFd = mDownloadManager.openDownloadedFile(mDownloadId);

The full exception text is:

> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadProvider uri content://downloads/all_downloads/5 from pid=5300, uid=10080 requires android.permission.ACCESS_ALL_DOWNLOADS, or grantUriPermission()

Comment: `Why I am receiving Security Exception when I try to open a deleted downloaded file via DownloadManager?` What did you expect to receive instead?

Comment: `I can't handle this exception:`. Why not? Just catch it.

Answer (score 0):

is it working (opening) when you leave file untouched? it looks like some limit/bug in Downloader, but you can catch this exception by replacing this line

```
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
```

with more general

```
} catch (Exception e) {
```

both `SecurityException` and `FileNotFoundException`  extends `Exception`, so both will be catched

you may also split this for two separated `catch`es and when `SecurityException` is catched then additionally check that you still have proper permissions - if user leaved app for a while and removed manually this file (your test case) then he may also manipulate in apps system settings and revoked permission

Comment: Thanks for the answers. It works OK if I leave the file untouched. I handled it by checking the Uri on null value before trying to open file - `mDownloadManager.getUriForDownloadedFile(mDownloadId) == null`. But it is strange, that Download manager doesn't do this check by itself